# Extend direct burial electrical cable

Tags: electrical, uk

There is a direct burial electrical cable running from my house to the shed in the back of my garden.  This had been put in years ago, was inspected by a certificate electrician and confirmed as correct/valid installation.  If I had my ways, it would have been put in a conduit, but it wasn't.

The cable is connected to a separate 30A RCD in the CU in the cupboard, from there it goes under the floor, runs for about 6 meters to the rear wall, and then about another 20 meters direct burial under ground to the shed.  It then rises straight into the shed from under the shed's floor and connects to a sub-panel in the shed. In the shed, this powers a light fixture (led flood light - 20W) and a receptacle, which in my 10 years in the house has only been used for electric lawn mower and some hand-held tools (e.g. angle grinder).

The shed has lived its useful life and I will be replacing it soon.  When I replace it, I want to put the new shed further away from the house and the existing cable is too short - by about 2 meters or so. What are my options to extend this cable to the new shed location?  Ideally, I'd like to keep all of the cable underground, but I'm not sure if a junction box can be buried.

To the best of my knowledge, it's [this cable](https://www.screwfix.com/p/prysmian-6943x-black-3-core-4mm-armoured-cable-25m-coil/67843).  I am in the UK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the UK, I think the rules are similar to the US and Canada in that you can't bury a junction box, but you can bury a splice, except in the UK you don't call it a splice you call it a joint.

The hardware used to make the splice / joint must be rated suitable for direct burial.  If you search for "resin joint kits," you'll find something suitable, such as the [3M™ Scotchcast™ Resin kit Series 92-NBA](https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/948692O/scotchcast-92nba-resin-joints-ds.pdf).

Since repairing or extending underground cables comes up all the time, I'd be surprised if they were not readily available in local stores.

Comment: Ah! That's exactly what I'm after. I tried a quick search for this particular product, but couldn't find it in the consumer shops.  There is a specialist electrical shop 5 minutes away from my house - I'll ask there.

Comment: @AleksG you're always better off shopping where the pros do, not the consumer big box stores! ;)

Comment: @FreeMan Agree. I go to the consumer big-box shops for generic stuff as it's cheaper.  Anything more serious I get at the "pro" shops usually.

Comment: @AleksG Trouble is then, the pro shops *know* they only see you with hard problems.  The American experience is the big-box shops really take advantage of your loyalty, and their "low, low prices" are mostly mythical.  They are just betting that you'll only price-check them on commodity stuff like twin-and-earth.  On less commodity things like conduit joiners and 120mm boxes (an actual US size), big-box is twice the price!  I've learned never to trust them.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica So true! when I said "generic stuff", I did mean that kind of stuff. I am price conscious, but also quality conscious. I don't mind paying more for better quality - within reasons of course.  I usually price check almost everything I buy, unless I'm already in the shop and I remember that I need something fairly low-cost.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica DIY is **very** different in the UK.  There are basically *no* "big box" stores like Home Depot, etc.  What you find are small local hardware stores on the high street (mom&pop affairs with screws, hand tools, lamp cord... basic stuff) and then pro shops for everything else.  DIY is not a hobby in the UK like it is in NA, and for electrical it's basically not even allowed for a homeowner to do many types of modification work without an electrician.  OP doing this themselves is probably illegal unless they can find an electrician to sign-off on the work.

Comment: @J... As someone who has always UK for many years your comment is mostly wrong. We have plenty of big DIY stores, B&Q, Homebase and Wikes being the major chains i'm familiar with. There is no general prohibitoin on DIY electrical work, but some works are "notifiable" under the building regulations (exactly what differs between the constituent countries of the UK) and it can sometimes be easier to just hire an electrican who is a member of a self-certification scheme than to tangle with building control yourself.

Comment: Underground joints though are something you are only likely to find at a proper electrical wholesaler.

Comment: @PeterGreen As someone who also lived in the UK for many years, the contrast with north america is like night and day.  Ok, I concede, there are some DIY shops, but they're nowhere near as ubiquitous as they are in NA - not even close.  I found it was very, very rare for people do even basic stuff around the house in the UK - people just call a handiman or a tradesman or whatever.  Maybe that's different in more rural areas, I don't know, but my experience was that Brits don't know much about their homes at all, and were generally very hesitant to touch anything "trades-y".

Comment: @J... From experience, I can whole heartedly say brits aren't scared of attempting to do DIY, particularly those that are incapable of doing it, and then either hiding the terrible/dangerous/scary bodge jobs or calling somebody in to undo the mess.

Comment: @TomCarpenter It's not a question of examples, it's a question of numbers.  90% of americans live within 10 miles of a Home Depot, to say nothing of Lowes, Ace, etc.  Nearly 70% of US consumers spend time shopping in DIY stores.  The numbers aren't even remotely close in the UK.